# Printing a two dimensional array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I want to print a two dimensional array which I get from another method, see code:

```
int** getPrint(){
    const int EIGHT[7][5] = {
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }
    };
    return EIGHT;
}

int main(){
    int **ptr;
    ptr = getPrint();

    return 0;
}
```

What would be the best method to print this?

Comment: None, because you have *undefined behaviour* (returning a pointer to a local variable.)

Comment: Looping? And your code has UB.

Comment: `int **` is not the same as `int [][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 7
#define M 5

const int ( * getPrint( void ) )[M]
{
    static const int EIGHT[N][M] = 
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }
    };

    return EIGHT;
}

int main( void )
{
    const int ( *ptr )[M];
    int i, j;

    ptr = getPrint();

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ ) printf( "%d ", ptr[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or you could use a typedef. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 7
#define M 5

typedef const int ( *ArrayPtr )[M];

ArrayPtr getPrint( void )
{
    static const int EIGHT[N][M] = 
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }
    };

    return EIGHT;
}

int main( void )
{
    ArrayPtr ptr;
    int i, j;

    ptr = getPrint();

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < M; j++ ) printf( "%d ", ptr[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've got a small question left, what does "const int ( * getPrint( void ) )[M]" do exactly? I have never seen a [] behind a method.

Comment: @Jazula it is a function declaration that returns a pointer to an array. You can use a typedef as I sgowed that it would be more clear.